# Async method call from constructor using Caliburn.Micro in UWP

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, uwp

I have the following ViewModel structure:

- App.xaml.cs

  - MainViewModel

    - DetailViewModel

I navigate between MainViewModel and DetailViewModel by this code:

```
navigationService.For<DetailViewModel>().Navigate();
```

It is the constructor of DetailViewModel:

```
public DetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  GetData();
}

private async Task GetData()
{
  using (var context = new MyDataContext())
  {
    var result = await (from data in context.Data
                          select data).ToListAsync();
    DataList = new ObservableCollection<Data>(result);
  }
}
```

As I don't use `await` when I call `GetData`, the constructor should return very quickly and the list should be populated later.

I experience a *very slow navigation*, I click the item in the MainViewModel, the GUI freezes for a second and I see the Detail *when* the list is populated (debug shows that the constructor is completed before the list is done).

I see a warning that says:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed.

What blocks then? What else should I set?

Comment: i think because async does not create new thread. so it will run in main thread so GUI freezes. you have to use Task.Run() to run it on another thread.

Comment: How big is the data collection that is being populated?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary How could be async if the same thread is used? I don't think so.

Comment: Marking a method `async` does not mean it executes on a background thread. This entire method is executed in the UI thread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It is not that big, a few hundred items, it is a SQLite database.

Comment: Then you need to check if the `SQLite` driver is actually making an asynchronous call to the database.

Comment: As I learned (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14095306), the method is executed on its calling thread _until_ the _first await_ arrives. Then the control goes back to the caller and the _callback_ uses the GUI thread later (in my case). The `ToListAsync` should do the database query in an async way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the SQLite Entity Framework provider does not support true asynchronous methods. So, the call to `ToListAsync` is in fact synchronous, causing your delay.

The best way to solve this is to use `Task.Run` with `await` (*not* `ContinueWith` or `Execute.OnUIThread`):

```
public DetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  InitializeAsync();
}

private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
  try
  {
    DataList = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
  }
  catch
  {
    // TODO: Log
  }
}

private List<Data> GetData()
{
  using (var context = new MyDataContext())
  {
    return context.Data.ToList();
  }
}
```

Note the introduction of a `try`/`catch`; error handling here is necessary since `InitializeAsync` is being treated as a "top-level" asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer. I modified my code according to this (I had to add the `async` keyword to the `InitializeAsync` method).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this one instead:

```
public DetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetData();
        });
}

private void GetData()
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        var result = await (from data in context.Data
                            select data).ToListAsync();

        DataList = new ObservableCollection<Data>(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This way I get a new thread but the DataList items are not shown in the View if I use this approach.

Answer (score -1):

This way it works as expected:

```
public DetailViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetData();
        }).ContinueWith(
      (x) =>
      {
        Execute.OnUIThread(
              () =>  DataList = new ObservableCollection<Data>(x.Result));
      });
    };
}

private Task<List<Data>> GetData()
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        return await (from data in context.Data
                            select data).ToListAsync();

    }
}
```

Thanks for the advices.